# JS code - only my question get upload in my quiz, but not the answer options

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a quiz with more than one questions and each get 4 options with only 1 good answer.

I built an HTML empty container, so thank to JS the next question can upload itself when the answer has been submitted. But only the question appear, and none of the 4 options.
I'm using this code on JS, could you help me to find the error please?

```
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestionScore = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion (questionIndex) {
  var q = questions[questionIndex];
  questionEl.textContent = q.question;
  opt1.textcontent = q.option1;
  opt2.textcontent = q.option2;
  opt3.textcontent = q.option3;
  opt4.textcontent = q.option4;
};

function loadNextQuestion () {
  var selectOption = document.querySelector('input [type=radio]:checked');
  if(!selectOption){
    alert('Please select your answer.');
    return;
  }
  var answer = selectOption.value;
  if(questions[currentQuestion].answer == answer){
    score += 10;
  }
  selectOption.checked = false;
  currentQuestion++;
  if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 4){
    nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
  }
  if(currentQuestion == totQuestions){
    container.style.display = 'none';
    resultCont.style.display = '';
    resultCont.textcontent = 'Your score is' + score + 'out of 4';
    return
  }
  loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

Comment: If you will upload the HTML file it would be more clear for us to check the problem, for example from where the function "loadQuestion" take the value of "questionIndex" and what it's mean?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `opt1.textcontent` be `opt1.textContent`? Remember that JavaScript is case sensitive.

Comment: Omg, I just tried and yes now it's working. Thank you so much, my first time project, I should have been more careful with big cap :)